# setOnEditorActionListener is not working for Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, keyboard-events

I have been trying this `IME_ACTION`

```
 //Listening to the keyboard action
    mSearchEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == R.id.ime_search || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {

                performSearch();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but seems like it doesn't at all work on Lollipop devices.

Here is the XML code - I am completely sure that I am doing this right.

```
 <org.mapunity.widget.FloatingEditText
        android:id="@+id/fragment_search_edit_text"
        android:hint="Enter a Text to Search"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:floating_edit_text_highlighted_color="@color/color_primary"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/ime_search"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </org.mapunity.widget.FloatingEditText>
```

Please provide an input:

I **know** there are a lot of similar questions but mine is specifically about **Lollipop**, i.e. Android 5.0+.

Comment: have you checked in simple EditText instead of org.mapunity.widget.FloatingEditText ?

Comment: yeah I did. It didn't work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem that you did. So, I've done some testing with the devices that I have.

The results indicate that devices with API > 19 don't respond to IME_ACTION

So, the solution is just to remove the `if` statement in your code:

```
mSearchEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        performSearch();
        return true;
    }
});
```